# Work with PSDs in PHP

Tags: php, psd

I was recently asked to come up with a script that will allow the end user to upload a PSD (Photoshop) file, and split it up and create images from each of the layers.

I would love to stay with PHP for this, but I am open to Python or Perl as well.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick along with Magick++, you can then use imagick.

imagick has all of the calls necessary to convert PSDs from layers, including doing masks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [PHP PSD Reader](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3627.html), which should at least get you started.